# If $\{s_n\}$ is a sequence all of whose values lie inside an interval $[a, b]$ prove that $\{s_n/n\}$ is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis

**Question:** If $\{s_n\}$ is a sequence all of whose values lie inside an interval $[a, b]$ prove that $\{s_n/n\}$ is convergent.

If answer it this way,is this answer correct?

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. $\{S_n\}$ is contained in a bounded interval and is thus bounded; let $M$ be the maximum value of $|S_n|$ on $[a, b]$. By the Archimedean property of the real numbers, we may find a positive integer $N$ such that, for $n > N$, $1/n < \varepsilon/M$. But then, $|(S_n)/n| < |S_n|(ε/M) < ε$, so the sequence converges (to zero, in fact). (Note that there is a minor technicality here if $S_n$ is the zero sequence, but then, $S_n/n$ converges anyway.)

It is not true that $\{S_n\}$ necessarily converges to $b$. It can converge to any point of the interval, or possibly none at all. $\{S_n/n\}$, on the other hand, will always converge to $0$, regardless of the choice of $[a, b]$.

Edit: After thinking about it, a closed interval $[a, b]$ must contain at least one nonzero number. If you let $M = \max |x|$ on $[a, b]$ then you can get around the technicality with $S_n$ being the zero sequence, and since $\{S_n\}$ is a subset of $[a, b]$ the same inequalities follow.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct. You are using the boundedness of the terms and the known convergence of ${1\over n}$. Since you are using the Archemedean property, as you rightly pointed out, you might need to split the case when $a=b=0$. You can always fix this by changing $M$ trivially (Like using $M+1$ as the bound). It isn't as big an issue as you pointed out.

---

As always, there are multiple ways of proving this.

Another very similar approach is using *Squeeze* Theorem. This is based on the same idea (boundedness of the terms and known convergence of ${1 \over n}$).

\begin{align}
s_n&\in[a,b]\\
\therefore a\leq s_n &\leq b\\
\mbox{Given } n\geq 0,\\
{a\over n} \leq {s_n\over n} &\leq {b \over n}\\
\lim _{n\to \infty} {1\over n} &=0\\
\lim _{n\to \infty} {a\over n} &=0\\
\lim _{n\to \infty} {b\over n} &=0\\
\therefore \lim _{n\to \infty} {s_n\over n} &=0\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Assume $\max\{|a|,|b|\}>0$ (otherwise the sequence is null and there is not much to prove).

Note that $|s_n|\leq M:=\max\{|a|,|b|\}$ for all $n$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$. There is $N_\varepsilon$ such that $$\frac{1}{n}<\frac{\varepsilon}{M}$$ for all $n\geq N_\varepsilon.$

For example, we can take $N_\varepsilon=\Bigl\lfloor\frac{M}{\varepsilon}\Bigr\rfloor +1,$ which is a natural number strictly bigger than positive real number $\frac{M}{\varepsilon}$.

Then:
$$ \left|\frac{s_n}{n}\right| < \varepsilon$$
for all $n\geq N_\varepsilon.$

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking the maximum value of $|s_n|$ over all $n$ (which may not exist in the sense that $|s_n|$ may not actually attain a maximum value), just take some *positive* M such that $|s_n| < M$ for all $n$. Theny you don't run into any trouble with dividing by $0$.